# assembly x86 allocating array of structs dynamically using system calls

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls, brk

I need help with allocating memory with system calls in homework project.
I get a number 'x' from the command line argument and I need to allocating array of 'x' structs which include two fields of dword.

I tried do that using the brk system call but I think that I don't understand it pretty good, this is my try:

```
    mov eax, SYS_BRK                 ;using brk system call
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
    mov [CORS], eax                  ;CORS-the array of the structs
    mov [initialallocated], eax

    mov ecx, [dronesNumber]          
    shl ecx, 3                      ;8 bytes * numberOfDrones
    mov eax, SYS_BRK
    mov ebx, [CORS]
    add ebx, ecx
    int 0x80
    mov [CORS], eax

    mov ecx, dronesNumber
    here:
    .myLoop:
            mov eax, SYS_BRK                
            mov ebx, 0
            int 0x80
            mov [CORS + 8*ecx], eax        ;segmentation fault here
            mov eax, SYS_BRK
            mov ebx, [CORS + 4*ecx]
            add ebx, ecx
            int 0x80
            mov [CORS + 4*ecx], eax

        loop .myLoop, ecx
```

Comment: Four issues at least: 1) `CORS` is the **end** of the allocated memory not the start because you update that value after the brk 2) you set `ecx=dronesNumber` which is the address not the value (you are missing `[]`) 3) even if you load the value, you are accessing outside the array (since that is indexed from zero) and 4) what do you need the brk in the loop for?

Comment: Allocate once and carve that up into fixed-size chunks!  Also, after the first `brk` query, you know the break and don't have to keep making `brk(0)` calls.  So even if you were going to use a loop, this is twice as slow as needed.

Comment: @Jester thank you both, I understood the mistakes